Distribution of states in quasiparticles model and in SYK model
I am currently approaching the SYK model with a little Normal Fermi Liquid background (go easy on me, it's my first time!). I have encountered these slides by Sachdev, where at some point he talks about level spacing of many-body states. In particular it turns out that for a system with $N$ sites and with a quasiparticles description for low-lying energy states the energy level spacing goes like $1/N$ at the extremes of the gap and like $2^{-N}$ midgap.
Instead, for the SYK model, which does not allow for a quasiparticle description, the level spacing is exponential-like ($e^{-cN}$ with $c$ some number which changes in the low part of the gap and midgap).
I am a little lost understanding why the level spacing is like this in both cases. In particular, I lack physical intuition on the $1/N$ behavior in the first place; regarding the second, how is this behavior enough to conclude there are no quasiparticles?
Lastly, the represented energy gap in which many body excited states exist is finite (it has a maximum energy): I think this is because the hamiltonian is a finite matrix and therefore admits a maximum eigenvalue. I see the energy level distribution looks symmetric in the high part and in the bottom part: does this mean that the top levels are quasiholes excitations in the first case? It seems rather intuitive in a tight-binding scheme, however I am struggling with connecting it with the Landau Theory of Normal Fermi Liquids where quasiholes are "added" below the Fermi energy.
Thank you in advance.
